# Are Italian Dolomites different in landscape and experience compared to Austrian Tyrol region?

Tags: italy, austria, alps, dolomites

I'm planning a family trip and we all love the outdoors and moderate hikes. We already have firmed up plans for Switzerland and Paris but unable to choose between Italian Dolomites and Seefeld in Austria Reading up online is confusing since they both belong to the Tyrol region.

So would the experience be very different? My mom's 67 and really fit but I would rather choose a place that offers great vistas and also easy to moderate hikes. Any personal recommendations / pointers for further research are welcome.

Personal bias is towards the Italian Dolomites since there will also be amazing pizzas ..nom to Austrian cuisine..just that veggie options might be really limited there.

Comment: Having gone skiing in Austria many times I can confirm that I have never noticed a shortage of vegetables.

Comment: @simonatrcl that doesn't necessarily equate to adequate meals for a vegetarian.

Comment: @phoog True; I was a bit too flippant. But the Dolomite have 100' of 1000's of tourists visit every year and to my knowledge they do cater for vegetarians - I've been with some. I don't remember any comments on the quality, either for or against, but they were well-fed enough to support multiple days of hard skiing from first-lift to being chivvied of the mountain by the Ski Patrol.

Comment: Have you considered Southern Tirol (Suedtirol, Alto Adige) ? It feels about half Italian and half Austrian, has great mountains, nice climate, and good hikes. See for example https://www.suedtirolerland.it/en/leisure-activities/mountains-and-hiking/hiking-in-merano-und-surroundings/

Comment: In my personal experience, Austria is already a mixture combining the cuisine from Germany with the messiness from Italy ;-)

Comment: @Hilmar appreciate the tip ..looks fab !!!

Comment: @Hilmar Funny, when OP mentioned the Dolomites I already assumed they were considering South Tyrol ;) Guess I forgot (again) that half the Dolomites are Italian …

Comment: Both Italy and Austria are well suited for every diets. I just want to point out that Alto Adige / Süd Tirol typical cuisine has the Austrian imprint rather than the Italian one. Surely you can get food recipes nationally spread. Such as pizza or lasagne and so on.

Comment: E.g. [this](http://www.oscarkocht.com) looks like a good veggie option in Innsbruck, Tyrol/Austria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dolomites have their own distinct kind of rock formations sticking out on top of the mountains, e.g.:

[image: The Three Peaks of Lavaredo]

The Three Peaks of Lavaredo / Tre Cime di Lavaredo / Drei Zinnen ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tre_cime_di_Lavaredo.jpg), picture by Daniele Bonaldo, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en)).

[image: Gardena Pass]

Gardena Pass / Passo Gardena / Grödnerjoch ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolomites#/media/File:Gr%C3%B6dner_Joch.jpg), picture by Hejkal, [CC-BY-2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/)).

As @Hilmar suggested in the comments, in Southern Tyrol you have a mixture of Austrian and Italian influences. A part of Southern Tyrol is in the Dolomites.

Edit:

For easy hikes, check out [Alpe di Suisi / Seiser Alm](https://www.seiseralm.it/en/holiday-dolomites/seiser-alm.html).

Comment: Appreciate it ! Will do some reading up on the above